# Creating Bitmap using Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, imageview, picasso

I am creating bitmap using below code :

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
```

But, it takes more time to load.
I want to know that is it possible with Picasso library ?

So far, I have tried using Picasso as below :

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(src)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(image);
        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        image.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = image.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
```

where,

image is my imageview inside xml layout.
The Problem is that I don't have to show or display ImageView and directly have to generate Bitmap for it if possible with the use of Picasso library.

and one more thing to say that I can't execute the code using above way with Picasso. It gives me error **Illegal state exception** .

Answer (score 3):

Please check this

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 
       //get bitmap
      }
      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed() {
      }
}

private void someMethod() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}

@Override 
public void onDestroy() {  // could be in onPause or onStop
   Picasso.with(this).cancelRequest(target);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // bitmap instance and use it for your own
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed() {

    }
};

Picasso.with(this).load(yourImageURL).into(target);
```

Use the above code to obtain this.